# How to update an attribute of a table with another table withouth using join or merge

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I have a temp table called "customerInfo" as below:

```
|CustomerNumber |
|197210271883   |
|197210271883   |
|194905062891   |
|194905301380   |
```

And another table called "Person" as below:

```
|Id CustomerNumber  FirstName   LastName  |
|1  NULL            Jack        Axelsson  |
|2  198003147470    Sarah       Flöijer   |
|3  196305088491    Göte        Lagergren |
```

I need to Update CustomerNumber in the second table based on what
I have in the first one. As you see, There is no relationship between them and I can not leverage join or merge techniques.

What I tried was using two cursors. I totally have no idea if its a right way or not?

```
DECLARE @value1 bigint
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT CustomerNumber from customerInfo;

DECLARE @value2 bigint
DECLARE db_cursor_2 CURSOR FOR
SELECT CustomerNumber from Person;

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @value1   

OPEN db_cursor_2
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor_2 INTO @value2   


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   
           update Person set  CustomerNumber = @value1
           where CustomerNumber = @value2

           FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @value1 
           FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor_2 INTO @value2 
    END   

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
CLOSE db_cursor_2
DEALLOCATE db_cursor_2
```

Comment: what is your expected output after update table2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to trump over the existing values of CustomerNumber in your second table?

To do this, a cursor is not the best idea because they work sequentially. Maybe try something like this:

```
; WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT CustomerNumber, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) AS SNO
    FROM customerInfo
), CTE2 AS (
    SELECT Id, CustomerNumber, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) AS SNO
    FROM Person
)
UPDATE CTE2
SET CTE2.CustomerNumber = CTE1.CustomerNumber
FROM CTE1 
    INNER JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.SNO = CTE2.SNO
```

This has not been tested in SQL Server so there may be some faults but you get the point from the code above.

Comment: Thanks for the message. If I follow what you suggested, Person's table will be updated, but all attributes will be the same.

Comment: Then I haven't understood your question correctly. What do you want to happen with the attributes exactly?

Comment: Ok. Person's table needs to be updated. but the only criteria is getting the value from the corresponding row in the another table. meaning that as what you suggested, the row number is a perfect idea to join the tables, but why values after the update are all the same. they must look like as if we have copied them from the first table and paste to the second

Comment: I have updated the code. What you get as a result in Person table is: "197210271883, Jack, Axelsson", "197210271883, Sarah, Flöijer", "194905062891, Göte, Lagergren". Is this what you've been looking for?